# cannot create mysql database using cmd

Tags: mysql, cmd

I have this on my batch file:

```
drop database if exists inventory;
create database inventory;
use inventory;

mysql -u root -p inventory < C:\wamp\www\test\inventory.sql
```

And I already copied all the contents of

> C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin

Into

> C:\windows\system32

Just to make sure that it has the file that it needs to run. But when I executed the batch file. It just said that. create and use is not an operable command, it said it does not recognize the command.
I also tried setting the path to

> C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin

But still no luck. Please help

Comment: oops, did not see it's a half a year old question! How did it pop-up at top of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin` to system path.

To add path do this. Go to `My Computer > properties > Advanced System Settings > Advance > Environment Variable > select "Path" click edit` add the `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin` path at the end separated by `;`

Edit your `inventory.sql` file at the top add

```
 drop database if exists inventory;
 create database inventory;
 use inventory;
```

write this (see below) in a batch file

```
 mysql -u root -pYOURPASSWORD < C:\wamp\www\test\inventory.sql
```

remember there is no space between `-p` and password.

Execute the batch file this should work.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try the use of create schema , seems more appropriate !? I was gonna comment instead of answer, but seems disabled !? Might be a syntaxt issue with wamp mysql 5.1.3 . . not sure, just a try

Comment: you require min 50 reps to be able to comment. I think this is pretty stupid restriction by SO. Reps to comment should be as low as 10.